# How to assign/set attribute in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on other developer's code and i am not an JQuery expert so i need little help.

the below code works fine if i have multiple employeeIds but since the scanrio has changed and i will be having only one employeeId so my question is how can i replace the `each function` with a single node.

each/map:

```
 var employeeid = $("#<%= gridview1.ClientID %> [id*='myDiv']").map(function () { return $(this).attr("EmployeeId"); }).get().join(',');
```

i attemp to write:

```
 var employeeid = 'A23433';
```

but the problem is that i need a way to set the attribute (EmployeeId)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set an attribute like:

```
$(this).attr("EmployeeId", YOURNEWVALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the jQuery attribute accessor:

```
$(this).attr("EmployeeId", attributeValue);
```